# How can I cleanse a String to contain only digits (0-9) and the letter X (uppercase) only, using Java and Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, regex, isbn

I am taking an ISBN input by the user - may contain spaces and hyphens etc. - and trying to sanitise it to be only digits.

In Java and Javascript, I have used the following regex successfully

**Java** (isbn is a java.lang.String)

```
isbn = isbn.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

and, **JavaScript**

```
isbn = isbn.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

However, some ISBNs can have an X as their checksum character. For example, 'The book of days' by Sara Reinke is '155404295X'

How can I change the regex to allow X as well as digits?

**Update**: `[^\dX]` worked in JavaScript, but `[^\\dX]` does not work in Java.

**Update 2**: PEBKAC! I was sanitising in two places - I updated one but not the other. `[^\\dX]` does work in Java as well.

Comment: `isbn.replace(/[^\dX]/g, "")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `[^0-9X]` there? I think it will work in both Java and JavaScript.
P.S. But `\\d` should work in Java too...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna follow your solution you can exclude with ?:(values)
For your example it would be: `[^\d?:(X)]` tested in online java regex.